# Openshift port for node.js

Tags: node.js, port, openshift

I have a server that won't start correctly on openshift. This is my code:

```
var connect = require("connect");
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT  || 8080;
var httpServer = connect.createServer(connect.static(__dirname + "/public")).listen(port);
console.log("Listening on " + port + "...");
```

I keep getting this error:

info: socket.io started
warn: error raised: Error: listen EACCES
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 0
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
Listening on 8080...

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to bind the listening IP address to `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP`. Here is the example from my working code (I'm using Express) on OpenShift.

```
var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, ipaddress, function() {
    // Do your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 3):

We need to specify the binding to your OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP in your listen like:

```
var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1"; (do not forget quotes)
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
```